# @EnableSwagger2 forces microservice to register as UNKNOWN to registry

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-cloud, springfox

We are using Springfox Swagger 2.6.0, Spring Boot 1.3.3.RELEASE and Spring Cloud 1.1.2.RELEASE.

Annotated application class with @EnableDiscoveryClient is registered to the registry.

When the @EnableSwagger2 annotation is present, the discovery client (microservice) is registered as UNKNOWN. When the annotation is not present, the discovery client actually registers as what is specified in bootstrap.yml in property 'spring.application.name'.

Thus it is making impossible to call the microservice via the gateway, because it is not registered under its real name.

Using Springfox Swagger 2.5.0, this does not occur!

What goes wrong?

Comment: see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1398

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to spencergibb.
Just set eureka.instance.appName to ${spring.application.name}

This works for me.